# BrowserQuest не грузит

Tags: linux, html5, node.js

После ввода имени в BrowserQuest, идёт загрузка. Но она бесконечная. Неважно, включён сервер, или выключен. Ошибок не видно и быть не должно.
Взято с GitHub. Branch: prod.